# Setting System Service Security

Tags: windows-server-2003, citrix

I'm investigating an issue, which is described almost perfectly here:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX122238

I've followed the steps in Part 2 and confirmed that the WMI service does **not** have the correct permissions that Citrix requires.

My question: How do I change this? The MMC snap-in is read-only and I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at.

Citrix just say:

> If this is not present you must check Microsoft Group Policies to see what is being applied to this server. Change Group Policy to include rights to LOCAL SERVICE.

Which is not very helpful.

It's a Server 2003 R2 box on a very small 2003 domain. It does have GPO's applied, but I can't find any configuration relating to this and I know for a fact it's not a part of our standard rollout because otherwise I'd know about it!

Comment: While this is no longer an issue, I'd be interested in any resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either create a new GPO to deploy this setting, or add this configuration to an existing GPO containing related settings.

Open `gpmc.msc` and create/edit the GPO which will apply this policy.  Drill down:

- Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > System Services

In the right pane, locate "Windows Management Instrumentation".  Double click, or right-click and choose "Properties".

[image]

A new window will appear.  Check "Define this policy", select your required startup mode, "Automatic" in this case, then click "Edit Security".

[image]

The familiar "Security" window appears.  Click "Add".

[image]

In the selection window, click "Locations".

[image]

Choose the local machine at the top. If your domain is selected instead, you'll receive a "User not found" error when entering the user name.

[image]

Enter `LOCAL SERVICE` in the "Enter the object names to select" field.  Click "OK"

[image]

`LOCAL SERVICE` will now be listed in the "Security" tab.  Check the required permission(s) for this service, "Read" and "Start, Stop, Pause" in this example. Click "OK"

[image]

"OK" on the remaining open window and you'll be back to the Group Policy Management Editor.  Exit the editor and link the GPO as required.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this tomorrow and see if it did the trick